# Display changelog after eclipse plugin update

Tags: eclipse, performance, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I want to display changelog in first run after plugin update. I interested where should I keep information about version of plugin. I'm thought about preference `/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` but I'm not sure it's good idea.

Comment: That location is for preferences only. What do you mean by 'information about version of plugin'?

Comment: To display after update I want have place with version. Every time I run my plugin it would check if version is good and then don't display changelog, but if version is different it's gona display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Platform.getStateLocation` returns you a directory where you can keep any information you like.

```java
Bundle bundle = ... your plugin bundle ...

IPath dirPath = Platform.getStateLocation(bundle);
```

The directory will usually be `.metadata/.plugins/<your plugin id>` in the workspace.